# Does the barbarian rage ability 'Ground Breaker' work on plain earth?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

Does the barbarian rage ability '[Ground Breaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/ground-breaker-ex)' work on plain earth or other floor surfaces that have a hardness of zero?

Comment: Is plain earth really listed as having Hardness 0? I would imagine that its Hardness would have to be *quite* high in order prevent just sinking into it. It's certainly quite a lot of work to dig into...

Comment: @KRyan That was my thinking too, but the substances table didn't cover it.  http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#table-substance-hardness-and-hp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the power should work on surfaces with zero hardness. I refer to part in the description where they reference hardness:

> This attack automatically hits and deals damage normally. If the barbarian manages to deal more damage than the floor’s hardness, the space she occupies and all of the squares adjacent to her become difficult terrain.

Since this floor technically has a hardness of 0, then any damage will trigger that clause. Thus the power is easier to use on a soft floor.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward to me.  There was concern that the floor had to possess a hardness in order to be a valid target.